# Restoring a file from Git?

Tags: git, crash, restore

*The question is related to the question ["How to restore Git after fatal file system error?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/552832/how-to-restore-git-after-fatal-file-system-error), but for a single file.*

I need to get to last state 2009-07-27 23:58, where I need the file:

```
/Users/henri/BAckup/6-relationdiagram/Normalized_perhaps_DB/simple_schema0.tcuml
```

**How can I restore the file after a crash?**

**ADDED: Where will I find the file? What are they supposed to do?**

**Graham's tip**

```
$git checkout 63c6844fded9cfcdee14c9330be82557046b3e56 HENRI_suunnittelu_doc/6-relaatiotietokantakaavio/Normalized_perhaps_DB/simple_schema0.tcuml
```

**William's tip**

```
git checkout bee6763b55cf8259438aa575cedbb09d1d02b96a  HENRI_suunnittelu_doc/6-relaatiotietokantakaavio/Normalized_perhaps_DB/simple_schema0.tcuml
```

Comment: Typo in answer corrected.  It should be --since='...' (add an '=')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sometimes i delete a file or directory in my git local and i want to restore just that file.  i run the following command:

```
 git checkout -- filenameOrDirectory
```

note the spaces in between.

Comment: So without <sha> and with --, the file/directory is restored from the last commit.

Comment: yes, but its taking from your local repository.  So for example, if you had  "git pull" recently and then changed one particular file, then you decided you wanted to restore it to the point when you last did the git pull, you could use this command. I find it very convenient. It restores files to there last git pull state which is really your local repo state. You can try it. Delete any file  or directory and then run this, it should be restored.

Answer (score 4):

If you need to get a single file out of a commit that is in your repository then git checkout will do it for you. Specifically:

```
git checkout <sha> <filename>
```

will retrieve the file <filename> from the commit <sha> into your current working copy.  can be any reference to any commit, so it could be a branch name, a tag name, HEAD^^^^, or anything at all like that that you want...

Comment: "Not just one Class diagram" is the log message for that commit, not the commit ID. You need some way of referencing the commit - such as the SHA1 ID for the commit. git log should be able to give you that.

Comment: Change into top level of your git directory. Run 'git ls-tree -r --name-only master' to check if the file you want to recover is in 'master' (from included screenshot it looks like 2009-07-27 23:58 state). Run `git checkout  master -- <filename>`, where `<filename>` is at it appears in git-ls-tree output

Answer (score 1):

Do you have an uncorrupted copy of the repository anywhere?  If so, pull from there to your working directory and then checkout the file.  You can do:

```
git log --since='2009-07-27 23:58' --pretty=oneline -n 1
```

to get the hash you want and then get the file via:

```
git checkout <file> <hash>
```

If you have no uncorrupted working copies of the repository, you might try 'git fsck', but your chance of success is small or zero if files have been lost.