# How to restore files in git?

Tags: git

Suppose I git clone a repository. Then edit a file A and delete a file B. How can I restore my working copy to the original status?

Something similar to svn up.

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1193499/restoring-a-file-from-git

Comment: Your question sounds like you're looking for something similar to `svn revert`, instead of `svn update`. As you may be aware, `git revert` is something slightly different.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
git reset --hard HEAD
```

is the command that will fully reset your working directory to what was in the most recent commit of the current branch. Be careful. All the work in your commit before you do the `reset` will be clobbered, and you'll lose it.

If you only need to reset a single file without modifying anything else, `git checkout -- fileA.txt` will revert only that file (regardless of whether it has been just edited or fully deleted).